# Set the margin to zero in pdf device

Tags: r

Currently I use the codes below to set the margin into 0.5 inch as stated in help page of pdf. However, I want to set the margin of pdf device into zero for paper A4. How should I do this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
pdf('tmp.pdf', paper = 'a4', width = 0, height = 0)
op <- par(mar = rep(0, 4))
grid.rect()
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `pdf(paper=)` option will always add a margin. (Which kind of makes sense since most printers can't print right to the edge of a piece of paper.) You can kind of bypass that by setting width/height to the dimensions of A4 paper. Unfortunately the `pdf()` function only takes inch measurements for width/height but

```
pdf("mya4.pdf",width=5.8, height=8.3)
```

should be pretty close.